# Pandas Dataframe: Splitting a list of predictions into dataframe columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I am using a scikit-learn model ([kdtree](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html)) to make predictions.

Originally, I was trying to only take the top 3 which is done using the following code given a fitted model (clf), list of labels (labels), and test data (test):

```
_,neighbors = clf.query(select_columns(test),k=30)
top3 = [Counter([labels[idx] for idx in neighborSet]).most_common(3) for neighborSet in neighbors]
predict = [[x for x,_ in  idx] for idx in top3]
preds = pd.DataFrame()
preds['predict1'],preds['predict2'],preds['predict3'] = [x[0] for x in predict],[x[1] if len(x) > 1 else x[0] for x in predict],[x[2] if len(x) > 2 else x[0] for x in predict]
```

I am trying to generalize this to n predictions.

```
print len(predict)
465
print predict[0:2]
[[111111111, 22222, 33333, 44444, 55555, ...],[123,233,466,557,886, ...]]
```

What is the pythonic way to split up n predictions into n columns without specifically calling each prediction name.

Ideally, I would like to do something like this:

```
_,neighbors = clf.query(select_columns(test),k=30)
topn = [Counter([labels[idx] for idx in neighborSet]).most_common(n) for neighborSet in neighbors]
predict = [[x for x,_ in  idx] for idx in topn]
preds = pd.DataFrame()
preds['predict'+str(i)] for i in range(n) = [x[i] if len(x) > i else x[0] for x in predict]
```

I am looking for a way to efficiently split up a list of items into separate columns in a dataframe.

---

Edit: I was able to get this to work with a dictionary comprehension and pd.DataFrame.from_dict.

```
_,neighbors = clf.query(select_columns(test),k=30)
topn = [Counter([labels[idx] for idx in neighborSet]).most_common(n) for neighborSet in neighbors]
predict = [[x for x,_ in  idx] for idx in topn]
preds = [{'predict'+str(i+1):x[i] if len(x) > i else x[0] for i in range(n)} for x in predict]
preds = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(preds)
```

Is this the right way to do this or is there a better way.

Comment: Good question. Can you post a data snippet of `predict` for reproducible example?